# android: Enable activity title when theme is set to NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an app for which i have set the theme attribute to

```
@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

this works ok as my application is running fullscreen  without the window title bar
now in one of my activities in need to enable the window title so i can use the

```
setTitle()
```

is there a way to override the theme attribute in application.
i have tried

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

but that didn't help as the app now is not fullscreen and also does not have the window title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another theme attribute for your activity, in your manifest, beside the theme you setted for your entire application, something like you can see for my activity *NewsList*:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:theme="@style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity android:name=".Start" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".news.NewsList" android:theme="@style/Theme.Black"></activity>          
        <activity android:label="Details" android:name=".news.NewsContent"></activity>      
        </application>
```